# Do I need a swap space to use Hybrid-sleep?

Tags: swap, power-management, suspend

Battery levels setting is now handled by UPower on latest Ubuntu and other systems. Instead of using gsettings, one should now edit the file `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`.

As specified by that file:

```
# The action to take when "TimeAction" or "PercentageAction" above has been
# reached for the batteries (UPS or laptop batteries) supplying the computer
#
# Possible values are:
# PowerOff
# Hibernate
# HybridSleep
#
# If HybridSleep isn't available, Hibernate will be used
# If Hibernate isn't available, PowerOff will be used
```

That is, normal Suspend is not possible at critical battery level, but only HybridSleep. (That was posted as a bug [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82925).)

But Hybrid Sleep doesn't seem to be available on my system.

Could it be because I don't have a swap space? (That's what I think the bug reporter says: "PowerOff is the only option for machines lacking a swap partition".)

Comment: I would suggest adding a swap partition, even just a small one and testing for yourself. It would certainly look that way though.

Comment: Please comment when down-voting to give a clue on what's wrong and I'll fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 'Yes'.

After creating a swap partition both hibernation and hybrid sleep are available.

[Hybrid Sleep](https://superuser.com/q/1124966/162573) is **both** hibernation and sleep/suspend, but to the user it looks more like suspend. Like hibernation, it 'swaps' RAM data to the hard disk and can restore it even in case of power failure. It acts like sleep/suspend in that it refreshes RAM constantly and therefore (if the battery is not fully depleted) can wake up as quickly as normal suspend.